# Why am I not getting that hat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

I am not getting the `Fear & Loathing` hat (from http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/)  even after fulfilling the specified criteria.

Comment: @ChrisF - surely we are supposed to guess?

Comment: when did you delete your answer? If I remember correctly I had to wait a couple of minutes...

Comment: deleted the answer 5 mins ago

Comment: @Oded Why is your hat not listed in winterbash2014 ?

Comment: Secret hats are not listed.

Comment: @Oded Why are these hats secret then ?

Comment: So people can have fun finding them and figuring out how to get them.

Comment: You currently seem to have a history of not providing any references or links to posts that you speak of. Please remember to include links to relevant material in the future or we'll have to guess, which'll just lead to someone crying on the dance floor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a bug. You have the hat now.

Comment: May I ask you to check [me](http://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama) and the [Breaking Bad](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/breaking-bad) and [Sumo Judge](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/sumo-judge) hats this way ? I don't feel it would be good to report every single missing hat in a separate question :)

Comment: @TLama Sure but you have to meet me in the middle. What site do you think you should have the Sumo Judge on? What question do you think you should have to have the Breakin Bad for?

Comment: Oh, Sumo Judge is per site. Then no Sumo for me (yet :) Breakin Bad for [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27505123/960757) (OP asked about deletion, hence my pointless reopen vote).

Comment: @TLama All hats are per-site. And that question: a) it has to be an actual edit (i.e. body, not just tags), and b) please don't cast reopen votes on posts that shouldn't be reopened.

Comment: Ah, so retag was not enough. Surely, I won't do this again. Thanks for deletion of that Q and your extra support!